# How to use GeoServer Web Processing Service (WPS) with OpenLayers and WFS?

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, wfs, wps

I wanted to try creating WPS service in geoserver on web application. I wanted to know reference links or some help regarding using WPS on web.

Comment: I want to use this WPS service i have already install

Answer (score 2):

There are instructions for installing the Web Processing Server (WPS) extension to GeoServer [here](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/extensions/wps/install.html).

Comment: I want to use this WPS service i have already install

Comment: I've not installed it so won't be able to help with that.  I thought you were trying to find getting started type documentation.  I hope you don't mind but I have updated the heading on your question to hopefully match what you require more accurately.

Comment: No issue of changing question. Actually i wanted to perform WPS using OplenLayes JS(Java Script). where i will use geoserver WFS and perform WPS on this WFS. Can please help me out.

Answer (score 2):

Just follow the link posted by @PolyGeo , the second [page](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/extensions/wps/operations.html) shows how to use it and provides an example on how to perform a buffer operation.

Even better at the end there is a link to the [WPS Request Builder](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/extensions/wps/requestbuilder.html#wps-request-builder) which is a web based tool for constructing WPS requests. This should get you started quickly.

Comment: it seems this link is dead could you please renew that

Answer (score 0):

Besides the suggestions that @PolyGeo and @unicoletti already provided, I found the [Processing part of the OpenGeo Suite documentation](http://suite.opengeo.org/opengeo-docs/processing/index.html) to be the most helpful for starting to use WPS.

The out-of-the-box WPS processes available with the GeoServer WPS extension might not fulfil all your needs. In that case, you will have to develop your own WPS processes and take a deep look at the [GeoTools API documentation](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/api/index.html).

Disclaimer: I'm also a beginner regarding WPS.